# Check for text item in List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to check if a string item exists in a List. This what my code currently looks like:

```
print('Is this: ', version)
print('In here: ', old_versionList)
if any(version in a for a in old_versionList):
   print('Already Exists')
else:
   split_text = version.split()[0]
   print('Split text: ', split_text)
# Check if similar named exists
if any(split_text in b for b in old_versionList):
   list_index = [i for i, s in enumerate(old_versionList) if split_text in s]
   index = list_index[0]
   old_versionList.pop(index)
   old_versionList.append(version)
   update_list.append(version)
   print('Updated plugin: ', version)
 else:
  old_versionList.append(version)
  print('Brand new plugin: ', version)
```

This is the output:

Is this:
image_picker 0.6.7+14

In here:  ['image_picker 0.6.7+14', 'http 0.12.2', 'camera 0.5.8+11', 'sqflite 1.3.2+1', 'path_provider 1.6.24', 'rxdart 0.24.1', 'intl_translation 0.17.10+1', 'device_info 1.0.0', 'package_info 0.4.3+2', 'shared_preferences 0.5.12+4', 'after_layout 1.0.7+2', 'countdown_flutter 0.1.2', 'google_maps_flutter 1.0.6', 'geolocator 6.1.6', 'carousel_slider 2.3.1', 'url_launcher 5.7.10', 'permission_handler 5.0.1+1', 'flushbar 1.10.4', 'synchronized 2.2.0+2']

Split text:  image_picker

Updated plugin: image_picker 0.6.7+14

My expectation was that it should have found the version in the old_versionList and printed "Already exists"

Comment: I tested the first part of code and received "Already exists" in output. How did you declare `version` and older and `old_versionList`

Comment: Is this your _exact_ output? Because there's a line break after "Is this:" that should not be there. Could it be that `version` is `"\nimage_picker 0.6.7+14"`? Try `version = version.strip()`.

Comment: @tobias_k, yes thanks, the line break was causing the issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @tobias-k comment, I suggest you to change

```
if any(version in a for a in old_versionList):
   print('Already Exists')
```

to

```
if any(version.strip() in a for a in old_versionList):
   print('Already Exists')
```

to get rid of any unintended `\n`.

Also, if the condition `if any(version.strip() in a for a in old_versionList)` is accepted, `split_text` will not be instantiated, giving rise to an `NameError: name 'split_text' is not defined`.

Comment: About the name error: I guess the second `if` should actually be part of the `else`, since there's not really a need to find a "similar" version and update it if the exact version already exists.

Comment: @tobias_k you're probably right, but the proposed indentation did not confirm that

Comment: Apologies,  indentation was poor in the original post. I check for an identical match then if there isn't one I split and check if there is a similar name.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code

```
print('Is this: ', version)
print('In here: ', old_versionList)
if any(version in a for a in old_versionList):
    print('Already Exists')
else:
    split_text = version.split()[0]
    print('Split text: ', split_text)
# Check if similar named exists
if any(split_text in b for b in old_versionList):
    list_index = [i for i, s in enumerate(old_versionList) if split_text in s]
    index = list_index[0]
    old_versionList.pop(index)
    old_versionList.append(version)
    update_list.append(version)
    print('Updated plugin: ', version)
 else:
    old_versionList.append(version)
    print('Brand new plugin: ', version)
```

to this:

```
print('Is this: ', version)
print('In here: ', old_versionList)
if any(version.strip() in a for a in old_versionList):
    print('Already Exists')
    split_text = ''
else:
    split_text = version.split()[0]
    print('Split text: ', split_text)
# Check if similar named exists
if any(split_text in b for b in old_versionList):
    list_index = [i for i, s in enumerate(old_versionList) if split_text in s]
    index = list_index[0]
    old_versionList.pop(index)
    old_versionList.append(version)
    update_list.append(version)
    print('Updated plugin: ', version)
 else:
    old_versionList.append(version)
    print('Brand new plugin: ', version)
```